# Discard message in Kstream Spring kafka application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, avro, spring-kafka

I created a kafka stream spring boot application.
Input :
Json format

Output :
AVRO format

When I am parsing a Json, if its found to be corrupt or not valid, I want to skip it.

But Instead when I try to return empty AVRO class,Stream API (automatically published to output channel) returns

```
Exception in thread "AutonomousStreamListener-process-applicationId-31990c75-5965-42b6-906a-92e13855e40c-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=FAULT_MANAGEMENT, partition=0, offset=4, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of string of com.fujitsu.fnc.fums.faultMgmt.avro.model.Fault
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.npe(GenericDatumWriter.java:183)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:177)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:82)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:72)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:110)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:59)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:65)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
```

How to handle such scenario, It involves skipping a message in stream and not always return message.

Pseudo-ish code :

```
@StreamListener("Processor-input-channel")
    @SendTo("Processor-output-channel")
    public KStream<String, AVROClass> process(KStream<String, String> input){
        //parse input , map to fault and change received key to time stamp and send 
        KStream<String, AVROClass> kStream = input
                .mapValues(v -> service.getAVROResponse(v))
                .map((k,v)->KeyValue.pair((Long.toString((System.currentTimeMillis()))), v));

        kStream.foreach((k, v) -> log.info(String.format("Key: %s, Value: %s", k, v)));
        
        
        return kStream;
        
    }
```

[EDIT]:

Also, Application seems to stop there and stream thread closes. No new messages are entertained by application.

Any help on AVRO streaming exception handling and a pseudo code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter operation to skip the message.

```
@StreamListener("Processor-input-channel")
@SendTo("Processor-output-channel")
public KStream<String, AVROClass> process(KStream<String, String> input){
    //parse input, map to fault and change received key to timestamp and send 
    KStream<String, AVROClass> kStream = input
        .mapValues(v -> service.getAVROResponse(v))
        .map((k,v)->KeyValue.pair((Long.toString((System.currentTimeMillis()))), v))
        .filter((k, v) -> v != null) <<<< ADD YOUR CONDITION >>>>
        .peek((k, v) -> log.info(String.format("Key: %s, Value: %s", k, v)));
    return kStream;    
}
```

Also you won't need `forEach` to print each messages. This can be easily done with `peek`.

> Also, Application seems to stop there and stream thread closes. No new messages are entertained by application.

You can ignore the deserialisation exception by setting the [deserialization-exception-handler](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/05/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-4-error-handling) property value to `logandcontinue`. But if there are any errors in the message processing on the service side, you can wrap it with `try..catch` block to handle it.

Comment: It does not work as log and continue is a deserialization exception approach not a serialization one. Exception is when we try to produce records and encounter a null.

Comment: when you are producing messages, prevent the null values from being sent to the topic

Comment: no the issue is actually , i have a scenario where data maybe dirty and I have to skip it . But I am not able to as the moment I try to not return this message back to stream , I return a blank object or null and I get a serialization exception by producer inside the stream . I don't have control over data I receive.